# How To Copy or View Existing Vertex Parents

Tags: vertices, parent

I have a problem with Vertex Parent.
Is there a way to either:

1. Copy/Mirror a vertex parent of an object and paste it to another object,
2. View a vertex parent of an object to see which three vertices it's parented to.

The reason is I need to mirror an object that has a vertex parent, but I'm ashamed to say that I forgot which three vertices I parented it to and currently I'm unable to produce the same result.

Comment: I don't know the answer.  But perhaps, if the specific verts aren't so obvious, you could unparent and reparent so that then, you would know?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but if do that, since I don't know which verts I used, I'm unable to re-parent the previous child without changing the results. I'm working on deformable and jiggly mesh so the difference became quite obvious when it's animated x﹏x